# Fill observableCollection directly from sql server

Tags: sql-server, observablecollection

I would like to know if there is any way to fill ObservableCollection directly from SQL server.
Currently I am loading my data into DataTable (using sqlDataAdapter) and do a conversion to ObservableCollection manually and it very inefficient.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have found a way to do this:

It can be done using SqlDataReader.

```
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> LoadCategoriesData()
{
    Command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, Connection);
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ObservableCollection<DataItem> myColl = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
    Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int mainCatID = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string categoryName = reader.GetString(1);
        //adding row data to observable
        myColl.Add(new DataItem(mainCatID, categoryName));
    }
    Connection.Close();
    return myColl;
}
```