# How do I fill a ListView from a data base using the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

How do I fill a ListView from a data base using the MVVM pattern? I prefer the EntityFramework but currently I am doing this with a SQLAdapter so I would already be happy with a working solution.

I have a class libary which I call Models. This libary contains a class called ProjectCompletedModel.vb

```
Public Class ProjectCompletedModel

    ' Read this article if the Auto-Implemented Properties do not match your needs:
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd293589.aspx

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get or set the project number.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>Set the project number</value>
    ''' <returns>Get the project number</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ProjectNumber As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get or set the project name.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>Set the project name</value>
    ''' <returns>Get the project name</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property ProjectName As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get or set the customer name.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>Set the customer name</value>
    ''' <returns>Get the customer name</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property CustomerName As String
End Class
```

Next I have a class libary ViewModels. It contains the class ProjectCompletedViewModel.vb

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class ProjectCompletedViewModel

    Private projCompleted As New Models.ProjectCompletedModel

    Public Property Projects As ObservableCollection(Of Models.ProjectCompletedModel)

    Public Property ProjectNumber As String
        Get
            Return Me.projCompleted.ProjectNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.projCompleted.ProjectNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ProjectName As String
        Get
            Return Me.projCompleted.ProjectName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.projCompleted.ProjectName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CustomerName As String
        Get
            Return Me.projCompleted.CustomerName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.projCompleted.CustomerName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The code for my view is the folowing:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectCompletedView"
             x:Name="WpfUserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:designheight="400" d:designwidth="400" Background="#D7E4F2" d:DesignWidth="918" d:DesignHeight="478"
             >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel x:Key="projComplObj"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="lvProjects" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,52,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">

            <!-- Define the column names -->
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ProjectNumber" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectNumber}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ProjectName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Customer" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                </GridView>                
            </ListView.View>            
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It leads to following design by adding some hard coded values in the constructor of the .xaml.vb file.

```
Me.lvProjects.Items.Add(New ViewModels.ProjectCompletedViewModel() With {.ProjectNumber = "0123456",
                                                                                                .ProjectName = "Alpha",
                                                                                                .CustomerName = "AlphaCustomer"})
```

[image: GUI0]

The goal is to group customers or any column that's why I want to work with a ListView. Never mind about the grouping I already have the code for that my first issue is loading the ListView from the DataBase with MVVM.

My application has a reference to ViewModels. ViewModels has a reference to Models.

Looks like this:

[image: architecture0]

I am able to fill the ListView with CodeBehind by generating a DataTable and assigning the DataTable.DefaultView to the ListView.ItemSource. By using the "DisplayMemberBinding={Binding TableName}" option I can display my data very fast and easy. But I want to keep it reusable and maintainable. => MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a good start for MVVM. One thing that you should understand is the concept of DataContext and DataBinding for WPF.

For reusability, I commonly use DataBinding of the View (you could bind your ViewModel to controls, but I prefer to use a ViewModel for the view containing ViewModels for controls…)

In the code behind of the view, I use the DataContext to give a context for my view. The ViewModel contains the ObservableCollections that will be bound.

```
// C#
base.DataContext = ViewModel;
// VB.Net
Me.DataContext = ViewModel;
```

I guess that you already have a binding since you have

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Following this View-ViewModel binding, I can give a Binding to my ListView!

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyJokers}"
    [...] />
```

MyJokers is actually the name of my Property in my ViewModel (note that the property must be setted Public)

```
public ObservableCollection<JokerViewModel> MyJokers
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    private set { _myCollection = value; }
}
```

You can then bind your ListViewItems on the public properties of this ViewModel (since the ListView will contains the sub-ViewModel children). You can customize your ListViewItems with ItemTemplate if the need exists.

With this binding, you can actually modify your ListView and ViewModel easily.

Comment: With the help of this guy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179967/fill-observablecollection-directly-from-sql-server your instructions made me solve this problem. Thanks! You can adapt it easily in VB.NET. Simply change base.DataContext = ".." to Me.DataContext = New ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my answer to incorporate the context binding.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the ListView in this way:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,52,0,0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
```

The ItemsSource property of the ListView must be set to the public property Projects of the ViewModel. Now from the viewmodel you can populate and fill the ObservableCollection(Of Models.ProjectCompletedModel) with your data.

You can remove the Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel x:Key="projComplObj"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for our quick response. I will work on it and report you as soon as possible.

Comment: I have removed the UserControl.Resources and it didn't mess up my application. I am interested in why I could remove it without breaking anything. Thanks.

Comment: You did'nt need any resource inside the XAML, because you have already add a datacontext in the View with <UserControl.DataContext><vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: In alternative, you can let the viewmodel inside the Resources, you can remove the block <UserControl.DataContext><vm:ProjectCompletedViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>. And you must set the external Grid in this way : <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{StaticResource projComplObj}">.

Comment: You helped me solving some issues. Thanks. But by following the instructions of Etienne it worked. But thank you very much you helped me much.